# autofac and owned instances

Tags: c#, autofac

I have been reasing about owned instances and I have a need to set one up.
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html

I have 2 methods in the same class that use this owned instance. I have set it up like this:

```
private readonly Func<SessionDetails, Owned<ITroposUnitOfWork>> _paramatizedTroposUnitOfWork;
```

My unit of work class constructor looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used for creating manual sessions
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sessionDetails">The details of the session to be created</param>
public TroposUnitOfWork(SessionDetails sessionDetails)
{

    // Throw if we don't supply any details
    ThrowIf.ArgumentIsNull(() => sessionDetails);

    // Start the session
    StartSession(sessionDetails);
}
```

So, my understanding is that if I use a **using** block, then the unit of work will be disposed of at the end of the call. But it isn't.
Like I mentioned before, I have 2 methods that use this owned instance. They are:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates the Tropos user
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The user to be created</param>
/// <param name="password">The password to set</param>
private async Task CreateTroposUserAsync(User model, string password)
{

    // If there is no password, throw an error
    ThrowIf.ArgumentIsNull(() => password);

    // Get our master user
    var user = await base.FindByNameAsync(model.Master);

    // If we have no master user, throw an error
    if (user == null) throw new ObjectNotFoundException();

    // Create our session details
    var sessionDetails = _troposSession.Value.Create(user);

    // User our new user
    using (var troposUnitOfWork = _paramatizedTroposUnitOfWork(sessionDetails))
    {

        try
        {

            // Create our tropos user service
            var userService = new TroposUserService(troposUnitOfWork.Value);

            // Create our user
            var transaction = userService.Create(model);

            // Save our changes (Don't throw an error if the user already exists)
            troposUnitOfWork.Value.RunTransaction(transaction);

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {

            // Display human readable messages
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // Sets the new users password
    SetTroposPassword(model, password);

    // Update the flag
    model.HasTroposLogin = true;
}
```

And the other one is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the tropos password
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The user that needs the password setting</param>
/// <param name="password"></param>
private void SetTroposPassword(User model, string password)
{

    // Create our session details
    var sessionDetails = _troposSession.Value.Create(model.UserName);

    // Create our anonymous session
    using (var troposUnitOfWork = _paramatizedTroposUnitOfWork(sessionDetails))
    {

        // Create our tropos user service
        var userService = new TroposUserService(troposUnitOfWork.Value);

        // Set our password
        var transaction = userService.ChangePassword(password);

        // Save our changes
        troposUnitOfWork.Value.RunTransaction(transaction);
    }
}
```

The first method does invoke the second method, but outside the **using** block. I put a breakpoint in the **TroposUnitOfWork** dispose method and it only gets hit once. The constructor is only hit once too.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: We need to see the initialization of  _paramatizedTroposUnitOfWork . What class has the CreateTroposUserAsync method? We need to see the cinstructor of that class. Why do you new up

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the initialization of  _paramatizedTroposUnitOfWork. 
What class has the CreateTroposUserAsync method? We need to see the constructor of that class. I suppose your overall goal is to get a unit of work implementation.

The reason why you only hit constructor once, might be due to the lifetime you used when registering. If its Owned. Then the two methods probably execute in the same lifetime scope and the dependency is only resolved once. Or put differently the _paramatizedTroposUnitOfWork(sessionDetails) returns the same instance.

I've solved similar problem using decorators and factories

```
public interface IEventHandlerFactory<in TNotification> where TNotification 
    : class, IAsyncNotification
{
    IAsyncNotificationHandler<TNotification> Create( ILifetimeScope 
                                                           lifetimeScope );
}

public class EventHandlerFactory<TNotification, TEventHandler> : 
       IEventHandlerFactory<TNotification>
       where TNotification : class, IAsyncNotification
       where TEventHandler : class, IAsyncNotificationHandler<TNotification>
{
    public IAsyncNotificationHandler<TNotification> Create( ILifetimeScope 
                   lifetimeScope )
    {
        return lifetimeScope.ResolveNamed<TEventHandler>( "EventHandler" ) 
                      as IAsyncNotificationHandler<TNotification>;
    }
}
```

full .net fiddle is here https://dotnetfiddle.net/fw4IBw